Simplification of boolean expression algorithms allowing multiple input gates
I am looking to algorithmically generate simplified diagrams of boolean logic that exists in a DCS program. I have come across a number of online boolean expression simplification tools, that use De Morgan rules or k-maps or things to simplify expressions, but their idea of what constitutes the simplest output doesn't seem to agree with what I would expect to be the simplest form to display on a diagram. For example, the expression AB + AC + AD is treated as simplified, but what I would want for this is A(B+C+D) because when I draw a diagram I can display these as follows:
A-->|
    |[AND]-->|
B-->|        |
             |
A-->|        |
    |[AND]-->|[OR]-->f(A,B,C,D)
C-->|        |
             |
A-->|        |
    |[AND]-->|
D-->|


simplifies to:
A---------->|
            |[AND]-->f(A,B,C,D)
B-->|       |
C-->|[OR]-->|
D-->|

Are there any algorithms, techniques, tools, etc. that address simplifying a boolean expression where gates of more than 2 terms are allowed and counted as 1 gate (so an OR with 3 terms in my example)? Or maybe its possible to use the normal rules and then add a final step of factoring to what I consider the simplest form?
My idea of the simplest form would be the fewest gates where each gate can be an AND or an OR accepting any number of terms. NOTs don't take up much space on a diagram, so I would think that the fewest number of NOTs would just be a tie breaker if the number of gates was the same.
As a bonus, what if there were multiple expressions, and I wanted to draw all of them using the fewest gates? For example a common pattern found in DCS logic is that a pump will shutdown if various conditions occur (high temperature, high discharge pressure, high vibrations, etc) but there might be permissives to start the pump and one of these is that no shutdown conditions are active, so the permissive and the shutdown are two boolean expressions, and they probably share quite a few parts, so a good simplification would likely combine the parts that are shared between the two.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logic_synthesis, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logic_optimization, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Espresso_heuristic_logic_minimizer
